# Last Question on CI-CD edx.org Final Exam

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, configuration, builds

**The problem:**

An organization is developing a solution that contains

```
a web application project
class library projectS
```

You manage a continuous integration pipeline for the application.

Each time code is checked in, you must

```
build both debug and release configurations in parallel
```

*The most recent build has compile errors for the release configuration but not for the debug configuration.
Developers confirm they have tested the release configuration correctly works on their devices.*

**QUESTION: What is the reasons for the build issues? (SELECT ONLY ONE)**

(i know "what IS the reasonS is just unfair, but it's as it is!!)

**o** The parallel builds caused contention issues for shared solution files.

**o** The web application references assemblies from the debug folder of the class libraries debug.

**o** A developer set their configuration to debug in Visual Studio.

---

For me is B.

NOT A, because you can use MSBuild Task's BuildInParallel option.

NOT C, because developerS confirm THEY have tested the RELEASE config (ON THEIR DEVICES)

---

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that the answer is most likely to be B, although it may be A under some circumstances.

- **A**: You can and should use `BuildInParalell` however sometimes this causes a race condition, for example, it could be that a developer omits the `$(Configuration)` in an output path meaning that both the `Debug` and the `Release` build output a file to the same location, then it just becomes a fight to see which build actually gets and locks that file first.
- **B**: If a developer was referencing binaries in the `Debug` folder **and it was a clean checkout** then those assemblies wouldn't exist, although if they are being built in parallel on the same machine they, in fact, might exist.
- **C**: If a developer sets their configuration to Debug (or anything else for that matter) it will impact builds on **their** machine assuming you use the `/p:Configuration=Release` option on the `msbuild` command line on the CI/CD environment.

It's entirely possible that Azure DevOps or any other CI/CD tool could be configured to rebuild each configuration in a clean container, thus meaning Release and Debug are actually being compiled in their own sandboxed filesystem thus can't possibly conflict with each other.

This isn't a great question for an exam because there is not quite enough information to differentiate between options A and B.  Some exams do intentionally do this though, and often your best bet is to select the **least wrong** answer in which case I would select B.

Comment: I concur. The issue with B is most likely the cause. When referencing assemblies straight from bin/{debug|release}/** you have that race condition.  For A, you should not have race condition if you're actually using 2 job agents b/c for each agents, you could have a clean copy of solution to work with.

Comment: Wow full explanation! Yes it is B, thank you very much!